# Checking index of element error

Tags: arrays, swift, indexof, any

I want to check index of element in array:

```
var arr: [Any] = ["st","er","gh", 2, 5,"jk", 78 ]
print(arr.index(of: 2))
```

but I get an error:

```
error: cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: Any)'
note: expected an argument list of type '(of: Self.Element)'
```

Why console throws me this and how to fix it?

Comment: In order to use `index(of:)` the must adopt Equatable protocol.

Comment: Try to avoid heterogeneous arrays like this. They're a huge pain to work with.

Comment: Hah I was wondering if using this type of array is "acceptable" but now I know it is not. Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an heterogenous array you have to use the `index(where` API and check also the type of the element:

```
let arr: [Any] = ["st","er","gh", 2, 5,"jk", 78 ]
if let index = arr.index(where: { $0 as? Int == 2 }) {
   print(index)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use index(of:) the must adopt [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol

try this code

```
   var arr: [Any] = ["st","er","gh", 2, 5,"jk", 78 ]
        print(arr.index(where: { (item) -> Bool in
            (item as? Int ) == 2
        }))
```

Comment: Note that the result would be *optional* :)

Comment: You can use `if let`, `guard`  based on what you want to use